# Where can I find the documentation for the spring security taglibs?

Tags: documentation, spring-security, taglib

Where can I find the documentation for the spring security taglibs?
Tried to google but failed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all I ever needed.
http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/taglibs.html

There are lots of examples in the reference documentation.

Comment: Thanks I believe that will suffice!